Automating Spring Boot Development with Swagger Codegen
I'm looking to automate the generation of base Spring Boot application code using Swagger Codegen. I want the generated code to include the following components:
Controllers
Utility classes (APIUtil)
Services
Repositories
Entities
The generated code should implement a standard CRUD workflow for interacting with a NoSQL database. The controllers should invoke APIUtil methods, which in turn call service methods. Service methods should delegate to repository methods for CRUD operations.
I would like to customize the generated code using custom Mustache templates.
Goal: Generate a complete Spring Boot application structure with basic API endpoints and CRUD operations for NoSQL databases, accelerating new application development based on OpenAPI specifications.
